# jQuery - Load info from database, into different variables?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Basically I can do so it prints out for example one field from the table, but I want to have all of them to different tables or whatever, how would I achieve this? I got this as my save/load code:

```
// Save/Load data.
$('').ready(function() {
    if($.cookie('code')) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax/loadData.php",
            data: "code=" + $.cookie('code'),
            dataType: "json"
            success: function() {
                var json = $.parseJSON();
                var coins = json.coins;
                var lvl = json.lvl;
                $('#test').html('lvl: ' + lvl + ' coins: ' + coins);
            }
        });
        console.log('Loaded data from the database with the code ' + $.cookie('code'));
    } else {
        // Generate save&load-code
        var chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXTZabcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        var string_length = 64;
        var randomCode = '';
        for(var i = 0; i < string_length; i++) {
            var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length);
            randomCode += chars.substring(num, num+1);
        }
        // Save code in cookies & database  
        $.cookie('code', randomCode);
        console.log('Generated and saved code ' + $.cookie('code'));
    }
});
```

Note that I do know that I do not have a save-function/ajax yet, but I'm working on the load feature right now.

This is my loadData.php file:

```
<?php
include '../inc/_db.php';
$code = $_GET['code'];
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE code='$code'");
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['coins'];
}
?>
```

Simple enough, yeah. This prints out the amount of coins that belongs to the specific user. Here's the table structure:

[image: wohoo]

How would I go about to load both coins AND the lvl field, into different variables or alike, so I can use them properly.

Comment: Gather everything in one array and only do one echo: `echo json_encode($your_array);`. You would need to use something like `$.ajax()` instead of `.load()` as well.

Comment: You need to add a `success` function to your ajax call: `,success: function(data){}` and in that function `data` will be an object you can access like `data.code`, etc. By the way, you don't need to parse `data`, jQuery does that for you.

Comment: @jeroen Just as I removed my new comment, you answered, hah. Anyways, I edited my first code, could you check what's wrong? I'm getting "SyntaxError: missing } after property list".

Comment: You're missing a comma: `dataType: "json",`.

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting now, happen when I edited, anyways, so I don't have to parse data - should my once again edited code be correct? :P

Comment: Alright, not getting the error anymore, but it's still not having the decoded JSON output on the page?

Comment: `console.log(data);` will tell you exactly what you have and how you can access it. When you put `data` as a variable in your function definition like I did above...

Comment: You're 99% there and I have to go. Good luck!

Comment: I figured out what was causing the problem, basically it doesn't send my code. I'll open up a new question, thank you. :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Joroen helped you out with the ajax side and hopefully you added the comma he was talking about. The php/mysqli part can be written like this:

```
<?php
   include '../inc/_db.php';

   $code = $_GET['code'];

   $query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE code='$code'");

   $row = mysqli_fetch_array($query));

   print json_encode($row);
?>
```

In reality this code is scary because you're not cleaning any of the incoming data and using it directly in a SQL statement. Since you already know it's only allowing A-Za-z0-9 characters you should check the value of $_GET['code'] to make sure it's safe to use. I also highly recommend using mysqli prepared statements to avoid some of the funny stuff that can happen with tainted input.

Answer (score 0):

this is probably a bad programming practice but that is how i would do it.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
 $return =  $row['coins'].",".$row['id';  //separate the send the values as a comma-separated string
 echo $return;
```

}

the js would look like this

```
$('#coins').load('ajax/loadData.php?code=' + $.cookie('code'));  //collect the values here
var values = $(#coins).text();   //save the values in a srting
var array_of_values = values.split(",");  //split the string at a delimiter and save the values in an array
```

mind you, this is not likely to work if the query returns multiple rows

Comment: Please refrain from adding non-answers as answers instead of comments. You can do multiple things easily to gain the needed 50 rep to comment. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258612/560593

Comment: noted! but i tried that first tho, now i'm hunting for points

Comment: You could also turn this into an actual answer, if you believe that the answer to the question lies in doing another ajax call, show the code that would be needed and explain.

Comment: I suppose you mean I should send POST's asking for different information each time? I.E one for coins, one for level and so on? :P

Comment: Nobody's going to vote up or accept "answers" like this, so don't expect to be getting any reputation from this. Try to find questions which you can answer well instead of posting stuff like this