# $.ajax not POSTing my variable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

```
var code = $.cookie('code');
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/loadData.php",
    data: { 'code': code },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data.coins);
    },
    error: function(emsg) {
        alert(emsg.responseText);
    }
});
```

Basically it shows the response text and within it, it has: `Notice: Undefined index: code in D:\wamp\www\ajax\loadData.php on line 3` and I'm unsure why this is so, so if anyone could help me clear it up, I'd be grateful.

loadData.php:

```
<?php
include '../inc/_db.php';
$code = $_POST['code'];
$query = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM data WHERE code='$code'");
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($rows);
?>
```

Comment: Can you also show the first three lines of `loadData.php`?

Comment: Also just as a side note, both `success` and `error` are deprecated, instead use the `done` and `fail` callbacks.

Comment: @Amadan Edited it for you, with the loadData.php, it works if I visit the page in the browser with the ?code= (including the code I have that I'm using to test it out with) and it will print out the JSON for it.

Comment: Use a browser tool and report the *exact* URL that jQuery is using.. the problem should be evident after that.

Comment: Err, `type: 'POST'` and `$_GET['code']` aint gonna play nice together. Try `$_POST['code']`

Comment: You posted something similar http://stackoverflow.com/q/25633914/ an hour ago; it looks like an (almost) exact dupe/very similar question.

Comment: @Fred-ii- That was about how I would go about retrieving data and put them into variables/JSON which I got help with, so yes, it does look alike.

Comment: @Phil Changed it to POST, still doesn't work. It still returns that it's undefined.

Comment: What does your browser's *Network* development console say?

Comment: This is what it looks like if I enter the page directly: http://puu.sh/bj3qb/21f6d3877f.png

Comment: @Phil http://puu.sh/bj3vc/aad2fd23e4.png This?

Comment: @Woop you need to expand the POST request to `loadData.php` and inspect the request parameters. If you don't see an entry for `code` then something is wrong client-side

Comment: @Phil http://puu.sh/bj3Ja/7ecdf97cd2.png It seems to be sending it properly?

Comment: "when I enter the page directly" is a GET request, won't work with `$_POST`. If you do a `$.ajax({ type: 'POST'...})`, you won't get anything in `$_GET`. You can't test one using the other.

Comment: @Amadan I figured the field below that was the POST request body

Comment: Sorry, missed that, foreign language and all :)

Comment: @Amadan http://puu.sh/bj3RF/1d3d512fcc.png Here? Let me know if I'm wrong.

Comment: By the way, try replacing `code` in clientside to `' or 1;--`, I wonder if it will work...

Comment: (Obligatory [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) link)

Comment: I seem to get returns from it with the correct information, I updated my question with the code I'm using now, I'm unsure how I'm using this information, tried a bunch of console.log's but no success.

Comment: None of those work because your code breaks when you try `JSON.parse` on something that is not a string; consequently, none of the `console.log`s are reached. Remove that and just try `console.log(data)`.

Comment: For future readers, be advised that the code in the question has been edited to be correct, consequently the question does not make sense any more. OP, when you add fixed versions in the future, please add them as extra information, without replacing the original problem, since Stack Overflow is designed to be a searchable archive of problems and their solutions.

Comment: @Amadan, thanks for that link :) Im going to go read through answer you two guys wrote until I find a few to upvote. Because I kind of feel like you guys really debugged this thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the data parameter to proper json

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax/loadData.php",
    data: { 'code': code  },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    error: function(emsg) {
        alert(emsg.responseText);
    }
});
```

The error is stating that `$_POST['code']` is not set, therefor the first place to look is where you set it.

Comment: `dataType` tells jQuery what to expect the response to be like, has nothing to do with sending data to the server.

Comment: When I did that, it returns an empty array, or so.

Comment: Try again but `'code'` vs `code` if Im wrong I will remove, updated the answer

Comment: Yes, it is. How would I use this information? $.parseJSON(data); doesn't seem to be working for me. (unless, of course, I'm doing something wrong, which wouldn't be a surprise)

Comment: If you set `dataType` to `"json"`, the response is already JSON-parsed into an object, just use it directly.

Comment: I printed out (data), and it prints out Array [ Object ], then I tried printing out data.coins, and it returned ReferenceError: coins is not defined

I'm sorry if I seem to be asking for everything to be handed to me, but it's the first time I'm actually using JSON and what not, which is why it's really new to me. :b

Comment: You are returning an array `$rows`. Arrays don't have `coins`. Try `data[0].coins`.

Comment: @Amadan I meant to post data.coins* :p But the [0] did the trick, thanks guys.